# Best pratice to store data fetched from server into android app

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

1. For my app I have a simple API to push/pull JSON data from server.
2. Suppose I fetched a list as a JSON array
3. I saved that JSON array into file "**my_list.json**" with MODE_PRIVATE access. I am saving the list to show when app is just started without network connection.
4. Also I am showing the list data (JSON array converted into Object array) in a List View.
5. In this listview User can select an item and delete that particular item (deleting through API calls, so in server DB that item is deleted) and that is disappeared from list.
6. Since I didn't delete that item in saved file "**my_list.json**" deleted data is appearing again when app is started.

I know maintaining a sqlite DB in my app solves this problem. But without using DB -

Is it good practice to save list data as JSON into file in android app ?

What is the elegant solution for such cases without using database in my app?

Comment: If all of the info in file my_list.json resides in the listview adapter then write the file again from data in the adapter (Object array) after every delete.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to alter the data the way you want the best way is to use SQLite database, which will allow you to query, update and delete the records you save .. which is a way better solution than using shared preferences or files.

[Here's](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html) an excellect tutorial of how to implement it

Comment: I know that sir, I also know how to implement sqlite for android. But the fact is in my app there will be few list data like I mentioned in above and in each list data there will be max 50-60 items. For these little requirement I am not willing to write code and design db. That's why I am asking. But obviously I will go for sqlite db if there's not any other ways. :)

Comment: Here'a a nifty work around, by the end of your user's edit .. let's say your activities onDestroy() transform your List<Object> to JSON and overwrite the one you have saved, if the data like you say is quite simple.
You can add a little check if no items were deleted don't update your saved file.